# Xamarin/.net MAUI iOS Map Handle click of built in annotations on map

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, maps, maui

I've got a custom maphandler for iOS in our .net maui app to handle platform specific code for ios devices map functionality. Im trying to replicate the functionality that is present in the standard iOS map app that allows the user to click on the landmarks/annotations on the explore version of the map. In the below example I want to be able to catch the touch event when they click on something like "Kahului Airport" or "Sunshine Helicopters". In the standard iOS maps app when you click on those locations the text animates and the flyout view comes in from the bottom with that locations details. I just need to handle the click event and take it from there. All the events I try to listen to don't return. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Are you using the [map control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/map?view=net-maui-8.0)? Can you try to [Interact with a pin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/map?view=net-maui-8.0#interact-with-a-pin) and show the relevant information?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Im not wanting to interact with a pin that i've placed on the map. Im wanting to simulate the inbuilt apple maps functionality where if you click on a location on the map it will focus it and bring up a popover of information.

Comment: @Matt you are adding event listeners? And none of those events trigger? I really want to see some code, to replicate it.